# Extract values from a fixed-width column

Tags: linux, awk

I have text file named `file` that contains the following:

```
Australia              AU 10
New Zealand            NZ  1
...
```

If I use the following command to extract the country names from the first column:

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

I get the following:

```
Australia
New
...
```

Only the first word of each country name is output.

How can I get the entire country name?

Comment: Try something like this for your awk:

`awk -F '[\t]+' '{print $1}'`

You just need to tell it what the Field Separator is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,15)}' file
Australia
New Zealand
```

Comment: Thanks  it works just needed to get rid of the white space:

Comment: awk '{print substr($0,1,22)}' | awk NF

Comment: @p.Trinx: Just to be clear: The `awk '{print substr($0,1,22)}' file | awk NF` command from your previous comment does _not_ trim trailing whitespace (the `| awk NF` part is an effective no-op with your sample data), but other answers here do show how to trim.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Raymond Hettinger's helpful POSIX-compliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43010698/45375):

It looks like your country-name column is 23 characters wide.

In the simplest case, **if you don't need to trim trailing whitespace**, you can just **use `cut`**:

```bash
# Works, but has trailing whitespace.
$ cut -c 1-23 file
Australia              
New Zealand
```

**Caveat**: *GNU* `cut` is not UTF-8 aware, so if the input is UTF-8-encoded and contains non-ASCII characters, the above will not work correctly.

---

To **trim trailing whitespace**, you can take advantage of ***GNU* `awk`**'s nonstandard `FIELDWIDTHS` variable:

```bash
# Trailing whitespace is trimmed.
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS=23 '{ sub(" +$", "", $1); print $1 }' file
Australia
New Zealand
```

- `FIELDWIDTHS=23` declares the first field (reflected in `$1`) to be 23 characters wide.
- `sub(" +$", "", $1)` then removes trailing whitespace from `$1` by replacing any nonempty run of spaces (`" +"`) at the end of the field (`$1`) with the empty string.

However, your Linux distro may come with Mawk rather than GNU Awk; use `awk -W version` to determine which one it is.

---

For a **POSIX-compliant** solution that **trims trailing whitespace**, extend Raymond's answer:

```bash
# Trailing whitespace is trimmed.
$ awk '{ c=substr($0, 1, 23); sub(" +$", "", c); print c}' file
Australia
New Zealand
```

Comment: If you need to grab the country code and the trailing number as well, you can specify more field widths as `gawk -v "FIELDWIDTHS=23 2 3" '{...}'`

Answer (score 1):

to get rid of the last two columns

```
awk 'NF>2 && NF-=2' file
```

`NF>2` is the guard to filter records with more than 2 fields.  If your data is consistent you can drop that to simply,

```
awk 'NF-=2' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't relevant in the case where your data has spaces, but often it doesn't:

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
foo            bar       baz       etc...
```

In these cases it's really easy to get, say, the `IMAGE` column using `tr` to remove multiple spaces:

```sh
$ docker ps | tr --squeeze-repeats ' '
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
foo bar baz
```

Now you can pipe this (without the pesky header row) to `cut`:

```sh
$ docker ps | tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' | tail -n +2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
foo
```